# I want to center these bootstrap navbar links in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Items<span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Trophies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Medals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Souvenirs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

*** I have tried almost everything to center the links in the navbar in my CSS file but nothing worked. please help me.

Comment: Welcome, I recommend you create a jsfiddle to show your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```